# Updating live App ID for Push notifications

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have an app in the App Store which has a wildcard App ID. I want to add push notifications to it, but cannot as we have a wildcard App ID. This is the error I get:

**Only explicit App IDs can be used to access the Apple Push Notification service. Please use an existing App ID with a specific Bundle Identifier or create a new one.**

Can I create a new App ID for my app that is live in the store? Won't that cause issues? I'm confused as to how I can add push at this stage?

[EDIT]
Can I setup a new one using the same App ID, but use a new bundle identifier?

Cheers

Comment: +1 as i am in the same situation and the fact that you've been able to describe the situation. I didn't as the question as i couldnt describe my situation properly as i didn't understand what was going on. But you've done just that. if someone can help that would be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You can create a new App ID using the App ID prefix you created before, the bundle indentifier or the App ID sufix must be something else. This can't be a wildcard character.

So for example you now use the following AppID; ABCDEFGHIJ.*

It must be transformed to something like this to use the push notification service; ABCDEFGHIJ.nl.jeroendeleeuw.appname

Comment: Will this break the update process for a published application?

Comment: @GunnarHoffman So long as the actual app's bundle id remains the same, it should not impede the update process.

Answer (score 1):

The process of changing the app id is documented here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1680/_index.html

Updated - Mar 24, 2015:  The link is no longer online but you can still has here:

http://web.archive.org/web/20111006112505/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#/web/20111006170433/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1680/_index.html

As provided in the comments below.

Comment: Too bad that link is no longer valid.  I need to change my App ID.

Comment: Seems this might be the successor to QA1680 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011159-CH18-SW1

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20111006112505/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1680/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

Michael Morrison's comment contains the info you (likely) want.  At the bottom is what you're really looking for.

**The link:**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011159-CH18-SW1

**The helpful section:**

> Updating Your App to Include APNS, iCloud, In-App Purchase, or Game
>   Center Requires an Explicit App ID
>
> As you develop, you might want to add features to your app. To support
>   APNS, iCloud, In-App Purchase, or Game Center, you need an app signed
>   with a provisioning profile that uses an explicit app ID. If you have
>   an app that uses a wildcard app ID, you need to create a new app ID
>   and then modify your provisioning profile.
>
> To update your app ID: Identify your app’s current bundle ID in Xcode
>   or iTunes Connect.
>
> Create a new app ID in the App IDs area of the iOS Provisioning Portal
>   with your app’s bundle ID search string.
>
> Enable your app ID for APNS or iCloud (see “Configuring Your App ID
>   for Apple Push Notification Service” or “Configuring Your App ID for
>   iCloud”). Explicit app IDs are automatically enabled for In-App
>   Purchase and Game Center.
>
> Modify your provisioning profile to use the new explicit app ID.

Answer (score 0):

Contact apple. If you change the bundle ID, your app will be uploaded as a new program. You can't do Push Notification with a specific bundle ID.

Comment: Can I use the same App ID but different bundle identifier?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that question.