# Reusing a wildcard appId to enable push notifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have recently taken over an iPhone project and I have never used objective-c before.

I have to get the application to use push notifications, but the first appId is already live and uses a wildcard (so no push notifications).

I created another appId with an identifier and got push notifications to work.
However my workplace would like me to get notifications to work for the wildcard app (since we already have lots of customers using that app).

So how can I make the wildcard app *update* and use a unique identifier without creating a new appId (even with the same bundleId).

I am very new to all of this, so a step by step process is greatly appreciated (ELI5).

For reference I used keychain to get the private .p12 file and I use that on a windows server that runs a console app that generates the push notifications (sent to Apples apns server).

EDIT: I have done the following steps, can someone tell me what im missing?

1) Create new bundleId (using the same AppId).

2) Configure that AppId to use push notifications.

3) Create the CSR in keychain.

4) upload that to the portal and create a production cert.

5) Download that cert and export the private key.

6) Create a provisioning profile using the same bundleId as 1 (e.g. au.com.website).

7) Download that provisioning profile, put it in x-code and on my iPhone device.

8) In the build settings of x-code use the bundle Id and use the provisioning profile I created in step 6.

9) Archive the app, deploy by ad hoc, save the file to the desktop.

10) put that file in TestFlight, download the app from testFlight on my iPhone.

11) put the private key on my windows server and send the push notifications (they send w.o errors).

I don't get push notifications (the iPhone is set to revive them).

Once again this is working with another appId someone else made, so I know the code works.

Answer (score 12):

Do not confuse the app identifier and the bundle identifier. The bundle identifier is something like: com.company.appname and is defined by an app's info.plist

The app identifier has an additional prefix (usually the team prefix) and can be containing wild cards. The app identifier is used to match bundle identifiers to provisioning profiles. A profile is only valid for that app that matches (excluding the prefix)

Now what you want is to keep the bundle identifier the same, because if you change that it becomes a new app. But you can change the provisioning profile and app identifier with every update.

I was in a similar situation a while ago when I had published an app with wildcard app id and I added an IAP to it.

- You just create a new (non-wildcard) app id that matches the bundle id.
- You enable the Apple services (IAP, GC, APNS) you require on the app id.
- You create new provisioning profiles to suit your needs (App Store, Ad Hoc, Development)

You can then submit an update for your app with the new profile but unchanged bundle id.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, what you ask is not possible.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011159-CH18-SW1

Here is an older question, that may have an answer...
[Updating live App ID for Push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840754/updating-live-app-id-for-push-notifications)

Answer (score 0):

For Push Notification an appId is must.
For a step by step process Use the two part tutorial of [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12). Hope this will help you.